# symfony 1_4 factories i18n param source container yaml

Tags: internationalization, containers, yaml, symfony-1.4

When I generate the translate container file (message.xml)

by using this command :

```
php symfony i18n:extract frontend en --auto-save
```

is it possible to replace the XML file by a YML file ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Symfony 1.x only rely on xliff file to handle internationalization. So you can't use a yml file for that.

> All translations are stored in a catalogue. The i18n framework provides a lot of different strategies to store the translations. We will use the "[XLIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF)" format, which is a standard and the most flexible one. It is also the store used by the admin generator and most symfony plugins.

As you can see [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/i18n), there is no function like `sfMessageSource_Yml` to handle i18n inside yaml file.

But you can handle translation in database. There are some plugins for that:

- [tmcI18nPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/tmcI18nPlugin)
- [mgI18nPlugin](https://github.com/rande/mgI18nPlugin)